# How select max value where like

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

How can get max value from following code, 
here is listing best ten tags

> Select id, tag, visit from tab_quotes_tag order by visit DESC limit 10;

id_| tag___|visit

23 |nikson    |  906

now should get best quote for each tag where 
Table quotes

### ID | quotes        | tagid              | counter

1  |bla bla bla    |     10,23,43       | 2323

2  |bla bla bla    |     3,45......           | 341

3  |bla bla bla    |     23,10,12| 5563

4  |bla bla bla    |     1,4 ......           | 164

> Select *, max(counter) from Quotes where tagid='23' or tagid like
>        '%,23' or tagid like '%,23,%' or tagid like '23,%'

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Write php code, execute query, fetch result.

Comment: Looks like you have CSV values in your column tagid. That is very bad DB design. You should read about normalization

Comment: show us the create table statement and example data...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(counter) FROM Quotes WHERE tagid = '23' OR tagid like '%,23,%';
```

Although your database design is very poorly writen. You should read about normalization.